# DataTable.Rows method doesn't return an IEnumerable<DataRow>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net

I am a big fan of using 'var' in C# rather than typing out all the data types. I find it annoying that

```
var dt = CreateAndPopulateDataTable()   // Immaterial
foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
```

returns the 'row' as an object variable rather than a DataRow variable. I know I can cast it later or just use 'DataRow' rather than 'var'. Are those my only two options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` by using the `AsEnumerable()` method against the table.

```
foreach (var row in dt.AsEnumerable())
```

However, in this case, you are hardly saving characters verus simply going ahead and specifying the type.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
```

Comment: really like the AsEnumerable.  Thanks a lot!